# Reading values from command arguments in C

Tags: c, command, arguments

Why cant i read the second value from command line using this code, i am using VS 2017 and have 4+3 in the command arguments

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
float numberOne;
float numberTwo;
float theResult;

if (argc == 2)
{
    sscanf(argv[1], "%f", &numberOne);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%f", &numberTwo);
    printf("%f \n", numberOne + numberTwo);

}
else
{
    printf("invalid input");
}

sleep(10);
return(0);

}
```

Comment: First of all, if `argc == 2` the valid indices are `[0]` and `[1]`, the value 2 says how many there are, not the highest index. And if you input `4+3`, without spaces, I would expect all of it in `argv[1]`.

Comment: Given the input format, you are using an inappropriate format string.  You should check the return value from `sscanf()` too.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass arguments as `4 3` (no `'+'` character between 3 and 4). `argc` is the number of command line arguments passed. By default, first argument is always program name. So, value of `argc` will be 3.

```
if (argc == 3)
{
    sscanf(argv[1], "%f", &numberOne);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%f", &numberTwo);
    printf("%f \n", numberOne + numberTwo);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this code is being tested using the inputs 2+4
15+17
1.395+2.890
1.562+0
2.391+a
a+2.695

Comment: @Squidly in that case, it willl fail the tests.  You will have to redesign.

Comment: my uni lecturer has some kind of bot that marks our code once submitted online, it inputs values using the + so i get it all wrong.

Comment: @Squidly; I am afraid that I can't help you in that. You have to rewrite the code so that it takes input in `a+b` form and then parse it and do the addition. If you have any problem after that then let us know.